# Does Human means Human lie?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), Oracle and Architect agree that the peace will last "as long as it can" and that
those humans who desire it will be offered the opportunity to leave the Matrix:

> Oracle: The ones that want out.
>
> Architect: Obviously, they will be freed.
>
> Oracle: I **have your word**?
>
> Architect: What do you think I am? **Human**?

Does Human means Human lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Human?" (an implied question, formed by intonation) can be understood literally as: "Do you think I'm human?"

This is a rhetorical question, since the architect is not expecting an answer. So, "Human?"  means "You know I'm not human."

What that implies about the architect is a matter of intepretation.  But, yes, it is implied that the architect thinks that humans are deceitful, and therefore the oracle can trust him.